# My physical server boot freezes at UEFI: MEM INIT after installing OS

Tags: uefi, lenovo

Model: LENOVO ThinkSystem SR250

Was able to boot into Provisioning Manager, set up RAID.

After installing Windows Server 2019, it reboots, then stuck at Power On Self Test - UEFI: MEM INIT\

Planned to upgrade UEFI firmware to the latest, but now I can't even boot into System Setup, F1 key has no response...

Any ideas?? THANKS

Comment: Could be either motherboard or power supply

Comment: clear your server's CMOS. [this Lenovo support link](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht510586-st250sr250-server-hangs-at-post-with-mem-init-after-updating-to-uefi-to-v200-or-201-lenovo-thinksystem) is literally the first item I found when searching for "MEM INIT".

Comment: funny that @Kantstandyourbitz thought I am a clairvoyant as there's no mention if this person already tried the official solutions, rather I don't assume anyone's level of competence, including yours. I'll pretend I didn't read the second part of your comment. try removing your case, remove its CMOS battery and short its clear CMOS jumper first.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.

Turned out to be that the SATA cable for drives 0-3 was still plugged into the motherboard, while it should have been plugged into the add-on RAID controller PCI board. (Caused by human oversight by the technician building the system.)